# MySQL select from a table and check in another table if the same value exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, I am creating a digital store.

Need some help on this part.

First my database is looking like this:

**products**
prod_id, prod_file_id, prod_status

**files**
file_id

So what I want to do is after they paid with paypal(already got the ipn working), it should plus the "prod_file_id" with one, and then check if the "file_id" exists in "files". If not it should put "prod_status" = 0.

Cant figure out how to do that, as im still new to coding.
Hope you are able to help me out, thank you.

Comment: For that products and files table must be related in some way.  what does prod_file_id store?

Comment: just an ID for each product. But there is only one product. Number "23".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

plus the "prod_file_id" with one:

```
update products 
set prod_file_id = prod_file_id + 1
where prod_id = 'the_prod_id_that_have_been_paid'
```

check if the "file_id" exists in "files". If not it should put "prod_status" = 0

```
update products set prod_status = 0
where prod_id = 'the_prod_id_that_have_been_paid' 
    and prod_file_id not in (select file_id from files)
```

Note: I assumed that prod_file_id is foreign key for file_id so that products and files table have proper relationship.

**UPDATE :**
I updated the second sql command. It should update prod_status if file_id **not** exists, so I make it `prod_file_id NOT in (select..`

Comment: First part is working "plus the prod_file_id".
But second part is not.
It does not update the product file status, if the file_id doesn't exists. It updates it when the id does exists. It should be the exact opposite. So if it dont exists it should update, else do nothing.

Comment: ah you are right, the second sql is doing the opposite. I updated my answer, only need **not** keyword added to make it do the right thing

Answer (score 0):

Try join products and files on prod_file_id + 1 = file_id